# include files by ID on same page

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to do this?

including file:

```
<?php
$_GET["id"];
case "fruits": include 'fruits.php';
?>
```

fruits.php:

```
<?php
$id = 'fruits';
echo 'hello fruits';
?>
```

I want to include files by the ID specified in the included file.
Thanks for help.

Comment: First fix typos&syntax errors in your PHP, than try to study difference between `$id` and `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: If `$_GET["id"]` is "hello", it should do `include 'hello.php'` or what?

Comment: done. I'm not sure if $_GET is only for form handling or to fetch any values from a seperate file.

Comment: @Snorlax: it should include any file where the id is "hello" or what ever.

Comment: Your question is very.. odd. You basically want to do this: `if($_GET['fruits'] == 'fruits') { include 'fruits.php'; }` or what? But using cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very incomplete, but here's an attempt at a solution for your problem.

```
<?php
// Get the ID parameter and change it to a standard form
// (Standard form is all lower case with no leading or trailing spaces)
$FileId = strtolower(trim($_GET['id']));

// Check the File ID and load up the relevant file
switch( $FileId ){
    case 'fruits':
        require('fruits.php');
        break;
    case 'something_else':
        require('something_else.php');
        break;
    /* ... your other test cases... */
    default:
        // Unknown file requested
        echo 'An error has occurred. An unknown file was requested.';
}
?>
```

Alternatively, if you have a long list of possible files, I would recommend the following:

```
<?php
// Get the ID parameter and change it to a standard form
// (Standard form is all lower case with no leading or trailing spaces)
$FileId = strtolower(trim($_GET['id']));

// Array of possible options:
$FileOptions = array('fruits', 'something_else', 'file1', 'file2' /* ... etc... */);

// Check if FileId is valid
if(in_array($FileId, $FileOptions, true)){
    // FileId is a valid option
    $FullFilename = $FileId . '.php';
    require($FullFilename);
}else{
    // Invalid file option
    echo 'An error has occurred. An unknown file was requested.';
}
?>
```

Switch statements with a lot of cases can get long and they can reduce readability. Hence, the second solution uses an array and the `in_array` function reduce the code length. This also allows you to easily see/manage which files are permitted.